# Carregamento de várias imagens através de Javascript

Tags: javascript, xhtml

Estou tentando carregar uma imagem através de Javascript mas não deu certo. No HTML está assim: `<img src="img/bola.jpg/>`, mas no Javascript não sei.

O código abaixo é para mostrar o carregamento de várias imagens, mas não sei porque não está carregando:

## Segue o Javascript:

```
/*
autor : Jose Lemo
descricao: Estudo cinema da baladinha
*/

// true = disponivel, false = indisponivel

window.onload = function(){
    carregarPoltronas(); // não está carregando a imagem
}

var poltronas = [false,true,false,true,true,true,false,true,false];

function carregarPoltronas(){
var imagens = document.getElementsByName("img");

for(var i=0; i<imagens.length;i++){      
    imagens[i].src = "img/disponivel.jpg"; 

    } 
}
```

## Segue o xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">     
  <head> 
    <title> JavaScript CinemaBaladinha</title>  

    <style>
      div{
        margin:0 auto; width:740px; text-align:center;height:250px;
      }
      #topo {
        background:url(img/baladinha.jpg) no-repeat; 
      }
    </style> 

    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/CinemaBaladinha.js"></script> 

  </head>      
  <body>   
    <div id = "topo"></div>

    <div>
      <img />
      <img /> 
      <img /> 
      <img /> 

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Alguém me pode dar um exemplo de como carregar uma imagem com Javascript?

Comment: Dica: não carregue a imagem dinamicamente, só está complicando. Define uma classe CSS para quando está disponível e adicione essa classe ao elemento. Então a imagem pode ir no estilo e não numa tag diretamente.

Comment: No entanto, alterar o `src` deveria funcionar. Suspeito que a URL sendo colocada não está certa ou esse código não está executando corretamente por algum motivo. Inspecione o HTML no seu navegador após a abertura da página e verifique se os valores estão corretamente definidos após a execução.

Comment: Esse que é o problema, tbem nao ta entrando no for. J inspeccionei o codigo xhtml. O hxtml está abrindo correto com a imagem no div #topo. O problema esta no javascript

Comment: suspeito que sua linha `var imagens = document.getElementsByName("img");` não está retornando nenhum elemento. Você procura por elementos com o atributo `name="img"`, e no seu HTML não existe nenhum elemento assim. Tente com `var imagens = document.getElementsByTagName("img");`

Comment: tayllan, Muito obrigado :D.Agora funcionou depois q fiz seu procedimento acima... vlw msmo

Comment: Depois voce vai tentar mostrar quantas poltronas estao livres ou nao utilizando aquele array, tipo isso: https://jsfiddle.net/zy8yp3rw/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O correto é `getElementsByTagName`:

```
var imagens = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

Alternativamente você pode usar `querySelectorAll`, que é mais flexível e permitiria filtrar melhor os elementos:

```
var imagens = document.querySelectorAll("img");
```

```js
function carregarPoltronas(){
  var imagens = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  for(var i= 0; i < imagens.length; i++){      
    console.log(imagens);
  } 
} 

window.onload = function(){
    carregarPoltronas();
}
```

```html
<div>
      <img />
      <img /> 
      <img /> 
      <img /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Ja deu certo troquei var imagens = document.getElementsByName("img") por var imagens = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); e deu certo. vlw pela sugestao ..